# Does the Toradora Anime end at the same point as the Manga/Light Novel?

Tags: toradora

I finished watching the anime however it seems unresolved

> While Taiga does visit the school after the credits allowing Ryuji to say he loves her they are still in separate schools

So I am wondering, does the anime end at the same point as the Manga/Light Novel? If not which of the Manga or the Light Novel does the story progress the furtherest (so I know which to get to continue and finish the story)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The light novel ended a little differently than the anime. The main light novel ends at Ryuuji beginning his third year of high school and meeting Taiga along his way to school, while the anime ends at their high school graduation, and then meeting Taiga in one of the classroom. In the light novel, she moved to a different, but nearby apartment block and her mother cancelled her drop out application from school. The manga has not been finished yet, so we don't know the ending of it per-se. I wouldn't call it the furthest in terms of plot, as it doesn't really cover their third-year high school life or beyond.

However, there is the Toradora visual novel that does cover what happens after their high school graduation. The Taiga ending reveals her to be with Ryuuji and pregnant.

Taiga's VN ending: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odOpaby7Fpk

Comment: I didn't think the anime ended at their graduation (despite talks about career planning we were given those when we had to select subjects for our graduation year). i thought that Toradora! Portable was a spin off since Ryuji looses his memories but it seems like it carries on the story so i guess that avoids me asking a question about it