# Why is the ending to the "ToraDora" light novel different from the manga ending?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, toradora

Why is it that the manga for *ToraDora* is different from the light novel adaptation? I know that the Manga and its respective Anime adaptation were made before the release of the light novel series, but what caught me when reading it was that the light novel ends with Ryuji going to his third year of high school and meeting Taiga on the way, while the Manga and the anime end with the main characters at their third-year graduation and Ryuji finding Taiga in a cleaning locker in their old classroom. The reason I am asking this is because I searched it on google, and this is the answer I got:

> "The light novel ended a little differently than the anime. The main light novel ends at Ryuuji beginning his third year of high school and meeting Taiga along his way to school, while the anime ends at their high school graduation, and then meeting Taiga in one of the classroom."

This quote came for this [website](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15108/does-the-toradora-anime-end-at-the-same-point-as-the-manga-light-novel#:%7E:text=The%20light%20novel%20ended%20a,in%20one%20of%20the%20classroom.), stack exchange. I tried to dig a little further but could not find an answer. If someone could answer this, that would be greatly appreciated.